# Meteor: JSON doesn't match SimpleSchema

Tags: json, meteor, simple-schema

I got this SimpleSchema for a collection in my meteor-app

```
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title:                  { type: String },
    slug:                   { type: String, unique: true },
    language:               { type: String, defaultValue: "en" },
    'category.element':     { type: String, optional: true }
}));
```

And I try to insert this JSON-data, but I get `insert failed: Error: Category must be an object at getErrorObject`

```
{
    "_id" : "25uAB4TfeSfwAFRgv",
    "title" : "Test 123",
    "slug" : "test_123",
    "language" : "en",
    "category" : [
        {
            "element" : "Anything"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is wrong with my JSON-data? Or what's wrong with my SimpleSchema. I can change both of them to match the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to define `category` as an *array of objects* in your schema:

```
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title:       { type: String },
    slug:        { type: String, unique: true },
    language:    { type: String, defaultValue: "en" },
    category:    { type: [Object], optional: true }
}));
```

This will get you unstuck.

If you want to be more specific about the contents of `category` then you can [define a sub-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/#combining-simpleschemas) for `category`. For example:

```
CategorySchema = new SimpleSchema({
    element:     { type: String }
});

Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title:       { type: String },
    slug:        { type: String, unique: true },
    language:    { type: String, defaultValue: "en" },
    category:    { type: [CategorySchema], optional: true }
}));
```

Comment: If I want to have `element: anything` in `category` (like shown in the JSON-data), then I have to define a subschema? Can you please give me an example - assuming the JSON-data is the format which I need?

Comment: Something like `category: { type: [new SimpleSchema({ element: {type: String, optional: true}})], optional: true }`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first declare the object, like,

```
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    ...,
    ....,
    category: {type: [Object], optional: true}
}));
```

After that you can extend/define object field(s) like,

```
Collection.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    ....,
    ....,
    category: {type: [Object]},
    'category.$.element': {type: String}
}));
```

use '$' if its a Array Object ([Object]), If only object then then do not use '$'.

If you do not sure about Object Structure, use another parameter `blackbox:true`
like,

```
category: {type: [Object], blackbox: true}
```